# Define generic type in superclass which refers to the type of the subclass it is in

Tags: java, generics

**Question**
Is there a way to implement a generic type or something similar in a superclass, which will always refer to the subclass it is in?

**Explanation of what i need**

I have the superclass

```
public abstract class MySuperclass{

   public abstract *magicalTypeReference* getInstance();

}
```

And when i create a subclass of it, i want the * magicalTypeReference * to become the type of the subclass it is in.

```
public class FirstSubclass extends MySuperclass{

  @Override
  public FirstSubclass getInstance(){return this;}

}

public class SecondSubclass extends MySuperclass{

  @Override
  public SecondSubclass getInstance(){return this;}

}
```

**Why a normal generic type wont do the job**

Something similar can technically be done with generic types.

```
public abstract class MySuperclass<E extends MySuperclass>{

   public abstract E getInstance();

}

public class FirstSubclass extends MySuperclass<FirstSubclass>{

  @Override
  public FirstSubclass getInstance(){return this;}

}

public class SecondSubclass extends MySuperclass<SecondSubclass>{

  @Override
  public SecondSubclass getInstance(){return this;}

}
```

But generic types do not guarantee that the type later is forced to be the subclass. Technically you can create a Subclass using another Subclass as the generic type. Like this

```
public class SecondSubclass extends MySuperclass<FirstSubclass>{

  @Override
  public FirstSubclass getInstance(){return this;}

}
```

Is there some construct in java that can provide a "type safe" way of implementing this?

Comment: What is your problem exactly ??? the code you provide is (almost) legal.

Comment: @C.Champagne the "solution" i showed in my last few snippets isn't "safe" as i described. Subclasses could reference each other. But i wan't the generic type to be the same type as the subclass. I made my question more obvious in an edit

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in Java.

Consider if hypothetically what you want were possible, you could implement `FirstSubclass` like this:

```
public class FirstSubclass extends MySuperclass {

  @Override
  public FirstSubclass getInstance() { return new FirstSubclass(); }

}
```

Then you could have a subclass of it that doesn't override the `getInstance()` method:

```
public class SubSubclass extends FirstSubclass { }
```

`SubSubclass` also implements the `MySuperclass` interface, due to inheritance. However, `SubSubclass`'s `getInstance()` method is inherited from `FirstSubclass`, which returns a `FirstSubclass`. Therefore, `SubSubclass` does not satisfy the contract of the `MySuperclass` interface since its `getInstance()` method does not return a `SubSubclass`.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of declaring your `MySuperClass` like

```
public abstract class MySuperClass<E extends MySuperClass>
```

if you declare like

```
public abstract class MySuperClass<E extends MySuperClass<E>>
```

you can make subclasses avoid referencing *each other* in a partial sense.

This solution will definitely avoid situations like this

```
public class SecondSubclass extends MySuperclass<FirstSubclass>{

@Override
public FirstSubclass getInstance(){return this;}

}

public class FirstSubclass extends MySuperclass<SecondSubclass>{

@Override
public SecondSubclass getInstance(){return this;}

}
```

where one class contains the other and vice versa.

Comment: Subclass1 extends Superclass<Subclass1>  makes it possible to use Subclass2 extends Superclass<Subclass1>. Vice versa isn't possible anymore, but still doesn't solve my general problem that the gereric type doesn't have to be equal to the subclass it is in

Comment: Thats why I mentioned that this solution works in a partial sense.

Comment: Wrote the comment before you edited. Saw it now. Don't think java offers a solution to my problem tho :/

Comment: Actually the declaration, `MySuperClass<E extends MySuperClass<E>>` only restricts the generic type of the argument whenever `MySuperClass` is called. In other words,  AnyClass `C` can extend the invocation `MySuperClass<A>` as long as the class `A`  satisfies the restriction `A extends MySuperClass<A>`

Comment: That is what i meant to hint at with my first comment, yeah